# Twitter mentions in the bio

Tags: twitter

When someone mentions @username in their Twitter bio, does the person get notified about this i.e their @username is mentioned in someone's bio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it with two of my accounts.

When I added an @mention of one of them in the profile of the other, while it made a nice link to the profile of that other account, I did not receive any sort of notification about it. Nothing in "interactions" or "mentions", and certainly nothing by email.

So the answer to your question would appear to be **No**.